# Javascript remove duplicate JSON records base on having the same attribute

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object

```
[{id:1,name:a, cat:1},{id:1, name:a, cat:2},{id:2, name:b, cat:8}]
```

I need it so that I just get the first of the duplicated id

```
[{id:1,name:a, cat:1},{id:2, name:b, cat:8}]
```

Comment: What have ***you*** tried so far?

Comment: Where is the **question** here? So far I see a ***work request***...

Comment: Personally - If you are the one making the JSON, in a webservice or otherwise, don't send information you don't want?  Also - just convert it to a actual json object and not the string representation of a json object... easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need to create a loop and a new array for names, loop through each of the items, if its name doesn't already exist in the new array, add it to a new object for distinct values, and then add its name to the new array to make a comparison with later.

I'm not writing that code for you though, maybe you can have a crack at it yourself now you have a concept to work with. :)